# output does not meet my expected result, how to fix it?

Tags: c++

my expected result is average=73.5 ,i have set the type of average as double but it result 73 what's the problem?

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main(){
int x=0;
int total=0;
double average=0;
int counter=0;

cout<<"Question 1"<<endl<<"Enter integer(-100 to end);";
cin>>x;
 if (x!=-100)
 {
     for(;x!=-100;counter++)
     {
         total=total+x;
         cin>>x;
     }

      average = total/counter;
 }
 cout<<"The average is:"<<average<<endl;


 return 0 ;
```

}

Comment: since `total` and `counter` are both `int`, the result of that calculation will be `int`. There are many ways to solve it - `(1.0*total)/counter` is one.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing integer calculations. Cast one of the integers to double:

```
average = ((double)total)/counter;
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, would static_cast<double> be preferable over (double)?

Comment: Just a syntactic difference. It's exactly the same in this case.

Comment: @lolando: I would certainly prefer `static_cast<double>(total)`: although in this case it does exactly the same, it would catch problems when it does _not_ the same, e.g., when the C-style cast would result in a `reinterpret_cast<...>()` or a `const_cast<...>()`.

Answer (score 1):

Integer operations yield integers as result. In C and C++ they never yield floating point results. You need to involve a floating point value in the computation, e.g.

```
average = (1.0 * total) / counter;
```